# Certain packages cannot be found in Sublime Package Control

Tags: macos, gosublime

I'm trying to install a package in Sublime on my Mac. I installed Package Control without a problem. When I activated Package Control, a list of packages showed up, but it only included packages from 1337 Color Scheme to Copy Relative Path in alphabetical order. Since I was trying to install GoSublime, I typed in "GoSublime", and immediately Package Control told me no package could be found. Both Sublime 2 and Sublime 3 act the same way. I figure it must be a setting on my computer that screwed this up. What could be the problem, or how should I diagnose it? Thanks.

UPDATE: As many others have mentioned, this does appear to be an issue these couple of days. Today the list shows items ranging from 1337 to those starting with Z. But GoSublime is still missing. Is it because the server is still under repair?

Comment: Same problem here, uninstalled all sublime 3 packages, trying to install again, but even Emmet can't be found.

Comment: I have the same problem. Mine goes from 1337 Color Scheme to Copy Relative Path as well and then stops. I checked my coworker Sublime and it's the same thing. Maybe it's just an issue for today? I installed a package last week.

Comment: I'm having the exact problem. My package list starts and ends at the exact same packages. It must be an issue with the service.